# How do I conditionally add attributes to components?

Tags: reactjs

trying to add some eleemnts to exist style properties,
how to destruct and add some elements conditionally

```
retun <div style={{...FULL, screenMinimized ? overflow: 'auto' : display:'none' }}>

...
const FULL: React.CSSProperties = {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ternary on the property value you are trying to set/override in the `style` prop object.

Example:

```
<div
  style={{
    ...FULL,
    overflow: screenMinimized ? 'auto' : 'hidden',
  }}
>
  ...
</div>
```

If you want to conditionally set *different* properties though you'll need to create each as a separate object to be spread into the `style` prop object:

```
<div
  style={{
    ...FULL,
    ...(screenMinimized ? { overflow: 'auto' } : { display: 'none' })
  }}
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I see, but what if elements are diffirent? please check the post